# Database is still locked even after disposing commands

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Good day I'm currenlty having a problem on my sqlite database in unity using c#.

So far whenever I tried to read my database it works perfectly fine.

But when I try to update it, it always gives me the "Database file is locked" even if there are no commands that are available yet or all commands are disposed and closed.

here is my code:

```
    string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/Database/SampleDB";
    IDbConnection dbconn;
    dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection (conn);
    dbconn.Open ();

    IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
    string sqlQuery = "UPDATE UserScore SET Highscore = '1'";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    reader.Close();
    reader = null;
    dbcmd.Dispose();
    dbcmd = null;
    dbconn.Close();
    dbconn = null;
```

I use this code in both the reading and  updating of the database. I also tried the "using" command
here is the code for reading :

```
using (SqliteConnection c = new SqliteConnection(conn))
{
        c.Open();
        using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(sqlQuery, c))
        {
            using (SqliteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                    currHighScore = rdr.GetInt32(0);
                    currHighDist = rdr.GetInt32(1);

                        Debug.Log( "High Score : " + currHighScore + ", High Distance: " + currHighDist);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is for updating:

```
using (SqliteConnection c = new SqliteConnection(conn2))
    {
    c.Open();
        using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(sqlQuery2, c))
        {
            if (MoveSanji.scoreAccumulate > currHighScore) {

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //or cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Apparently I have to restart Unity. I don't know how and why, but it worked. :) Thanks for the reponse :)